# Data Frame Transcode 1-0

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, transformation

I'd like to transform some columns of a data frame in [0,1].

I've a data frame like this:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
  A   NO  YES   NO  YES
  B  YES   NO   NO  YES
```

and I'd like to transform it in:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
  A   0     1   0    1
  B   1     0   0    1
```

Transforming `YES` in `1` and `NO` in `0`.

How can I do it with a loop? I'd like to set a loop because I have 10 columns... So it would be faster... On the other hand it is possible to use the indices of the columns (`[,1:10]`)? What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your variables are not factors, you can simply do:

```
df[df == 'YES'] <- 1
df[df == 'NO'] <- 0
```